# How does a PHP interface actually change the behavior of a class

Tags: php, object, interface, arrayaccess

According to PHP documentation,

> [Object Interfaces](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php) allow you to create code which specifies which methods a class must implement, without having to define how these methods are implemented.

Hence, an interface is like a class with predefined method which still needs to be accessed with the `->` symbol

However, the [ArrayAccess Interface](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) provides accessing of objects as arrays. Making it possible for an object to be accessed with both `$object->property` and `$object["property"]`

I cannot understand how the `ArrayAccess` makes it possible to change an object syntax. I've written out a code to try replicating the effect of *just one* of the `ArrayAccess` method but it throws an error

```php
// Using the PHP ArrayAccess Interface

namespace A {
    
    class myclass implements \ArrayAccess {
        public function offsetExists($offset) { return true; }
        public function offsetGet($offset) {
            // changed behaviour
            return $this->{$offset} ?? null;
        }
        public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {}
        public function offsetUnset($offset) {}
    }

    $myclass = new myclass();
    $myclass->access = 'Interface';
    echo $myclass['access']; // "Interface"

};

//Trying to implement my own ArrayAccess Interface

namespace B {
    
    interface MyArrayAccess {
        public function offsetGet($offset);
    }
    
    class myclass implements MyArrayAccess {
        public function offsetGet($offset) {
            // change behaviour
            return $this->{$offset} ?? null;
        }
    }
    
    $myclass = new myclass();
    $myclass->access = 'Interface';
    echo $myclass['access']; // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type B\myclass as array

}
```

Please help me explain this properly. Thanks

Comment: when you implement ArrayAccess, an object of your class can be accessed with the array-access _operator_ `[]`. Inherently, the appropriate interface method is called (by PHP)

Comment: "an interface is like a class with predefined method which still needs to be accessed with the -> symbol" - An interface can define abstract methods too. The PHP syntax used to access stuff inside classes doesn't have anything to do with interfaces.

Comment: `ArrayAccess` is builin, it's based on some internal implementation written in C. The interface here just exposes the functionality so you can apply it to your own classes written in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than to say that interface "change the behaviour of a class", I'd say interface makes it easy to **expand** a class functionality.

To understand interface, as an object-oriented programming concept, we should first understand what problem it is here to solve.

## What problem was "Interface" designed to solve?

Interfaces are kind of **contract**. It is the way to achieve [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) in PHP. You need to think in the perspective of a library writer, who wants to expose functionality to others. For example,

```php
class Greeter
{
    public function greet($person)
    {
        echo "Hello, {$person->getName()}!\n";
    }
}
```

To make sure that the library user knows that a `$person` needs to have a `getName()` method, you may create a class `Person` that has a `getName()` method. Then use [Type Declaration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) to detect potential error when the code is parsed.

```php
class Greeter
{
    public function greet(Person $person)
    {
        echo "Hello, {$person->getName()}!\n";
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string $name;
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Let's assume there is another library to feed things with food:

```php
class Feeder {
    public function feed(Eater $eater, string $food) {
        $eater->eat($food);
    }
}

class Animal {
    private $stomach = [];
    public function eat(string $food) {
        $stomach = $food;
    }
}
```

### Consider this...

Now, let's say a user want to write a class `Pet` that can both eat and be greet. The user don't want to write those features again just for `Pet`.

**How to write `Pet` so both `Greeter` and `Feeder` library can be used on it?**

Perhaps something like this?

```php
class Pet extends Person, Animal {
}
```

Unfortunately, PHP **DO NOT support multiple inheritance**. A class can only `extend` one single class. The above code is not valid. So in the current situation, user can only use either one of the libraries.

Also for different thing, "name" might be a very different concept (e.g. a person might return both `$first_name` and `$last_name` with `getName()`). There might not be a sensible default implementation of `getName()` method in your library class to begin with.

So you, as a library writer who want his / her library to be as flexible for user as possible. What can you do?

## How to solve this problem with "Interface" in PHP?

Interface is declaration of method signatures. It is a shortcut to declare library requirement without a concrete class / inheritance requirement.

With interface, you may rewrite both library like so:

### `Greeter` library

```php
class Greeter {
    public function greet(Namer $namer) {
        echo "Hello, {$namer->getName()}!\n";
    }
}

interface Namer {
    public function getName(): string;
}
```

### `Feeder` library

```php
class Feeder {
    public function feed(Eater $eater, string $food) {
        $eater->eat($food);
    }
}

interface Eater {
    public function eat(string $food);
}
```

Instead of requiring a concrete class (or parent class inheritance), a class is allowed to implement multiple interfaces. So the below `Pet` class is totally valid in PHP:

```php
class Pet implements Namer, Eater {
    private array $stomach = [];
    private string $name = '';

    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Implements Namer.
     */
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Implements Eater.
     */
    public function eat(string $food)
    {
        $this->stomach[] = $food;
    }
}

$greeter = new Greeter();
$feeder = new Feeder();
$pet = new Pet('Paul');

$greeter->greet($pet);
$feeder->feed($pet, 'a biscuit');
```

Now, an object of this `Pet` class can work both with `Greeter` library and the `Feeder` library.

## What about the `ArrayAccess` interface?

The [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface is an interface declared not by 3rd party library writers, but by core PHP writers. Core PHP writer provides even more profound support to it.

A bit like interface we mentioned before, PHP provides feature to class that implements it. But instead of our `Greeter` or `Feeder` examples above, core PHP provides [Syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to class that implements ArrayAccess. That means you may use **cleaner code** to work with classes implemented AccessAccess interface.

In the official example,

```php
<?php
class Obj implements ArrayAccess {
    private $container = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->container = array(
            "one"   => 1,
            "two"   => 2,
            "three" => 3,
        );
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        if (is_null($offset)) {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        } else {
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]) ? $this->container[$offset] : null;
    }
}
```

If you implemented them, then instead of these:

```php
$obj = new Obj;
$obj->offsetSet(10, "hello");
$obj->offsetSet(11, "world");
if ($obj->offsetUnset(12)) {
    $obj->offsetUnset(12);
}
echo $obj->offsetGet(11);
```

You may use `$obj` with array-like syntax to make your code shorter:

```php
$obj = new Obj;

$obj[10] = "hello";
$obj[11] = "world";
if (isset($obj[12])) {
    unset($obj[12]);
}
echo $obj[11];
```